# Spring JPA Oracle SUBSTRING

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I'm using a custom `@Query` with Spring JPA like this:

```
@Query(value = "select ua from USER_ACCOUNT ua where SUBSTRING(ssn, -4, 4) = :ssn and last_nm = :lastName and birth_dt = :dateOfBirth")
UserAccount findByLastFourOfSSNAndLastNameAndDateOfBirth(@Param("ssn") String lastFourOfSSN, @Param("lastName") String lastName, @Param("dateOfBirth") Date dateOfBirth);
```

It works without any problems when I run it locally, but as soon as I deploy it out to the development environment I get:

```
[2017-12-19T23:02:59,048] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
[2017-12-19T23:02:59,048] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING": invalid identifier

    [2017-12-19T23:02:59,049] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[User Store] Servlet.service() for servlet [User Store] in context with path [] threw exception [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
    java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING": invalid identifier

The development environment is pretty much identical to my local. Same database, same version of Tomcat. Am I just missing something obvious here?

EDIT: SQL being generated:

select useraccoun0_.GUID as GUID1_5_, useraccoun0_.CREATED_BY as CREATED_BY2_5_, useraccoun0_.CREATED_DT as CREATED_DT3_5_, useraccoun0_.DB_NOTE as DB_NOTE4_5_, useraccoun0_.LAST_CHANGED_BY as LAST_CHANGED_BY5_5_, useraccoun0_.LAST_CHANGED_DT as LAST_CHANGED_DT6_5_, useraccoun0_.ACCOUNT_RECOVERY_EMAIL as ACCOUNT_RECOVERY_E7_5_, useraccoun0_.ACCOUNT_RECOVERY_PHONE as ACCOUNT_RECOVERY_P8_5_, useraccoun0_.BIRTH_DT as BIRTH_DT9_5_, useraccoun0_.DISABLED_IND as DISABLED_IND10_5_, useraccoun0_.DISABLED_DT as DISABLED_DT11_5_, useraccoun0_.DISABLED_REASON as DISABLED_REASON12_5_, useraccoun0_.email as email13_5_, useraccoun0_.FAILED_LOGIN_CNT as FAILED_LOGIN_CNT14_5_, useraccoun0_.FAILED_PASSWORD_RESET_DT as FAILED_PASSWORD_R15_5_, useraccoun0_.FIRST_NM as FIRST_NM16_5_, useraccoun0_.LAST_FAILED_LOGIN_DT as LAST_FAILED_LOGIN17_5_, useraccoun0_.LAST_LOGIN_DT as LAST_LOGIN_DT18_5_, useraccoun0_.LAST_NM as LAST_NM19_5_, useraccoun0_.LOCKED_IND as LOCKED_IND20_5_, useraccoun0_.LOCKED_CNT as LOCKED_CNT21_5_, useraccoun0_.LOCKED_DT as LOCKED_DT22_5_, useraccoun0_.USER_PASSWORD as USER_PASSWORD23_5_, useraccoun0_.PASSWORD_CHANGED_DT as PASSWORD_CHANGED_24_5_, useraccoun0_.PHONE_NBR as PHONE_NBR25_5_, useraccoun0_.REQUIRE_PASSWORD_RESET_IND as REQUIRE_PASSWORD_26_5_, useraccoun0_.SSN as SSN27_5_, useraccoun0_.USER_NM as USER_NM28_5_ from USER_ACCOUNT useraccoun0_ where substr(useraccoun0_.SSN, -4, 4)=? and last_nm=? and birth_dt=?
```

Comment: Here's an idea. Look in the JPA provider log and tell people what SQL is being invoked by the JPA provider. Also think about the second arg to SUBSTRING ... cannot be negative.

Comment: And you are missing the alias on the attributes you have in the where clause. It should be ua.ssn and ua.last_nm and ua.birth_dt This will prevent problems in the future when adding a join and the columns could be duplicate

Comment: @DN1 It is my understanding that SUBSTRING should be converted to oracle's SUBSTR, which definitely can take a negative position. That just means it should start at the end of the string rather than the beginning. The SQL it generates looks correct to me, but it's like it is executing it with the "SUBSTRING" keyword rather than "SUBSTR" when it is deployed out on the dev servers.